# rails twitter bootstrap helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, helper, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am using the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem in my app. It seems to come with a range of helper methods that create for example the edit and delete buttons in a themed view:

```
<%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                  cohort_path(cohort),
                  :method => :delete,
                  :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')),
                  :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
```

Where are these t() methods and helpers defined? How can I alter them? For example, if I want to change the label on the Destroy button to "Delete" I can change the above to:

```
<%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => "Delete"),
                  cohort_path(cohort),
                  :method => :delete,
                  :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')),
                  :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
```

What I would really like to do is change `t("helpers.links.destroy")` to display "Delete" instead of "Destroy" in all my views. Can I do that? Appreciate your help!

Comment: Doooh. I found it. Nothing to do with Bootstrap. l18n translation API: t short for tranlation, l short for locale
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is add the following to your i18n Rails file (in path "config/locales/en.yml"):

```
<pre>
en:
 helpers:
    links:
      back: "Back Page"
      destroy: "Delete"
</pre>
```

The method t() is using to i18n a Rails Application.